# 3d object on wordpress using tree.js

Tags: wordpress, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to integrate a 3d object (.glb or .obj) on my website built on wordpress.

I've read that I can use tree.js and canvas but can't find a detailed tutorial on how to do it on wordpress.

this is basically the exact same thing I want to achieve, a 3d object that moves with the mouse, but at the right top of the page, not as a background or full screen :
https://staedelschule.de/en

can anybody help me this ?

thanks